# May wine be substituted with grape juice for Yom tov

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, grapes-wine, maseches-pesachim, orach-chaim

According to the [Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.109a.5) in Masechet Pesachim, there is a mitzvah to drink wine on Yom Tov for Simchah Yom Tov. My question is, can grape juice substitute for wine on Yom Tov?

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2020/05/26/simchas-yom-tov/